# Error:\--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1"

Tags: android

Could someone help me with this.
It's my coding in Android Studio for an app everytime I tried to compile, it gives this error:

```
"Error:\--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1"
```

Here is my code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.googlemap.luco.lucomap"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.65'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

}
```

Comment: Pretty sure play services < 8 is long gone.

Comment: If you are using `targetSdkVersion 25` or `compileSdkVersion 25` then you should also use recommended `buildToolsVersion` available for API level 25

Answer (score 2):

Try to use latest version of PlayServices library. You are using very very old version, which is **3.2.65**. Use **10.2.4** like below.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
```